# Insert from Select (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select  cast (count(*) as bigint) from 
(SELECT  oldtable.id,oldtable.day,newtable.newid from oldtable
left outer join newtable on oldtable.day between newtable.FROM_DAY 
and newtable.TO_DAY and oldtable.id = newtable.id) a
```

this results 4.5 billion

but when I say this:

```
INSERT  INTO AnotherTable
(id, day, newid)
SELECT  oldtable.id,oldtable.day,newtable.newid from oldtable
left outer join newtable on oldtable.day between newtable.FROM_DAY 
and newtable.TO_DAY and oldtable.id = newtable.id
```

it only inserts 300 million records (oldtable contains 4.5 billion records, newtable 430 million).

Why?

The definiton of AnotherTable:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE AnotherTable ,NO FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
 (  
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  day DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',  
   newid INTEGER NOT NULL
 )
 PRIMARY INDEX ( id) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE_N(day  BETWEEN DATE '2000-09-20' AND DATE '2030-02-15' EACH INTERVAL '1' DAY );
```

I made the following checking:

```
 SELECT oldtable.id,oldtable.day,newtable.newid from oldtable 
 left outer join newtable on oldtable.day between newtable.FROM_DAY and newtable.TO_DAY
 and oldtable.id = newtable.id 
 where newtable.newid is null
```

It resulted 0 records, so outer join is not needed at all, I just use it here to demonstrate that the record number is different, but it shouldn't be

Comment: Is it possible that you have a not-NULL constraint on `newid`?  This might be NULL due to the `left outer join`.

Comment: I made the following checking:

`SELECT  oldtable.id,oldtable.day,newtable.newid from oldtable
left outer join newtable on oldtable.day between newtable.FROM_DAY 
and newtable.TO_DAY and oldtable.id = newtable.id
where newtable.newid is null`

It resulted 0 records, so outer join is not needed at all, I just use it here to demonstrate that the record number is different, but it shouldn't be

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages from the database server at all? Were there any disk storage limitation issues? If it continues to fail, perhaps try generating insert statements from your SQL select, and then running the insert scripts afterward.

Comment: No error messages. Disk Storage set to be more than enough.

Comment: Can you post the table definition for `AnotherTable`? I have a hunch but would like to see the table definition first. (Actually post all table definitions if you can.)

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: AnotherTable.Id is an integer type. What is the largest value supported by the integer type your database (you haven't specified the type of database). If 4.5 billion records requires 4.5 billion positive integer ids, then there might be issues with the Id column handling values >~ 2.147 billion

Comment: It doesn't require that amount. oldtable contains flattened time intervals (every day is recorded), and the newtable is made to show the interval data in a compact way. It contains only 430 million integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get the number of inserts from?

4.5 billion minus 300 million is approx. 4.2 billion.

When you exactly calculate the number of missing rows is the result 4.294.967.296?

Then it might be due to "Warning: 6813 Numeric overflow in internal counters."

Cut&Paste from the Messages manual:

*6813 Numeric overflow in internal counters. The number of rows returned is actual number of rows returned, modulo 2^32.
Explanation: This warning message is sent within SUCCESS/OK parcel when the activitycount
(i.e., the number of rows) returned, overflows the current max limit of (2^32 - 1).
The request is successful.
The value returned to the user is : (actual number of rows returned) modulo 2^32.*

*NOTE: If the user knows that the actual number of rows returned cannot exceed 2^33, then the actual number of rows returned can be derived as follows:
actual number of rows returned = 2^32 + the value returned to the user.*

Dieter

Comment: I am no longer working at the company so I cannot check, but this seems to be the best reason

Answer (score 0):

You should create a multi set table. It will do the trick!

```
CREATE MUTLISET TABLE ();
INSERT INTO ()
SELECT ()
```

The above syntax worked for me!